# javascript how to make copy this text button

Tags: javascript, php, command-line

I want to make the action of copy this url with javascript , I used this script but it doesn't work !
//at the head

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

 function ClipBoard()
 {
 holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
 Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
 Copied.execCommand("Copy");
    }
     </SCRIPT>
```

at the body

```
 <SPAN ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
 <?php  echo $files[$i]." ";?>
 </SPAN>

 <TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
 <?php  echo "test";?>
 </TEXTAREA>
 <BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">copy url</BUTTON>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var n1 = document.getElementById('copytext');
var n2 = document.getElementById('holdtext');
  n2.value = n1.value;
```

**or**

```
var holdtext =  document.getElementById('copytext').innerHTML;
  Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
  Copied.execCommand("Copy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
function ClipBoard() {
    var copytext=document.getElementById("copytext").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("holdtext").value=copytext;
}
```